# i'm trying to format String in java

Tags: java, string

iam trying to form string in java to be like this

```
        String ss = String.format("%-20s %s", "itime1", " IQD\n");
        String bb = String.format("%-20s %s", "itw", " IQD\n");

                String NN = ss + bb;

                System.out.println(NN);

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, NN);
```

The OutPut in the log is :-

```
itime1                IQD
itw                   IQD
```

But in JOptionPane Is :-

```
itime1           IQD
itw           IQD
```

i need the output to be the same !

any help ?

Comment: Set fixed font on the JOptionPane

Comment: it is working ! but There is same for Arabic ?

Comment: No idea mate, sorry. You have to research this one yourself.

Comment: Ok mate Thinks ☑️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed Font for Arabic. `.setFont(new Font("Simplified Arabic Fixed", Font.PLAIN, 15));`